# Using pairs in list comprehension gives "redundant clause" warning

Tags: list-comprehension, isabelle

I get an odd-looking warning when I use the `(_,_)` pattern in a list comprehension. My minimal working example is as follows.

```ml
theory Misc imports 
  Main
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Numeral"
begin

definition "xys = [(1::int,2::int),(2,3),(3,4)]"

value "[x+4. (x,_) ← xys]"

end
```

Everything seems to work fine, but I get the warning

> The following clauses are redundant (covered by preceding clauses):
>
> x ⇒ []

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to be worried.

The syntax

```
[a+4. (a, b) ← xys]
```

is internally translated to

```
concat (map (λx. case x of (a, b) ⇒ [a + 4] | _ ⇒ []) xys)
```

(see the section "List comprehension" of `HOL/List.thy`).

What is happening here is that if your pattern `(a, b)` matches, it will be mapped to your expression `a + 4` (the first half of the `case` expression). If it doesn't match, it will be dropped from the output list (the second half of the `case` expression). In your case, the pattern `(a, b)` will always match, meaning that the second half is redundant---hence the warning.

In the ideal case, the list comprehension implementation would be modified to not generate the second half of the `case` expression if the pattern entered by the user will always match. Until this is done, it is safe to just ignore the warning.